# Move all items, with a certain value, to end of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects, there's a `state` value on each object.

I would like to order the array so that any obejects with a state of either `healthy` or `unhealthy` are pushed to the end of the array.

I'd like to group all `healthy` items together and all `unhealthy` items together also.

```
var people = [
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'unhealthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    }
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'unhealthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    }
];
```

I would like the final array to look like this:

```
var people = [
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'other'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'dead'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'healthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'unhealthy'
    },
    {
        name: 'XXX',
        state: 'unhealthy'
    }
];
```

I've attempted the following, but for some reason, some items in the array are missed.

I think possibly as I'm pushing items to the bottom, the index of all other items changes and I'm missing some?

```
_.each(people, function(p){
    if(p.state === 'healthy'){
        var arr_idx = people.indexOf(p);
        people.push(people.splice(arr_idx, 1)[0]);
    } 
});

_.each(people, function(p){
    if(p.state === 'unhealthy'){
        var arr_idx = people.indexOf(p);
        people.push(people.splice(arr_idx, 1)[0]);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object for the sort order.

```js
var people = [{ name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'other' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'unhealthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'other' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'other' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'other' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'unhealthy' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'dead' }, { name: 'XXX', state: 'healthy' }];

people.sort(function (a, b) {
    var order = { healthy: 1, unhealthy: 2 };              // easy to maintain
    return (order[a.state] || 0) - (order[b.state] || 0);  // return delta of order
});

console.log(people);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var people = [{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'unhealthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'unhealthy'}];

people.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.name === 'healthy') ? -1 : ((b.name === 'unhealthy') ? -2 : 0);
});

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.sort` to sort your `people` array like below:

```js
var people = [{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state:'unhealthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state:'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'unhealthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}];


people.sort(function(a, b) {
   if(a.state === 'healthy' ||
      a.state === 'unhealthy')
     return 1;
   else
     return -1;
});

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array.sort` to order values

```js
var people = [{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state:'unhealthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state:'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'other'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'unhealthy'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'}, {name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'}];

var orderMap = {
  'healthy': 10,
  'unhealthy': 11,
}
people.sort(function(a,b){
  var _a = a.state;
  var _b = b.state;
  var o_a = orderMap[_a];
  var o_b = orderMap[_b];
  if(o_a) return 1;
  else if (o_b) return -1;
  else return _a > _b ? 1 : _a < _b ? -1 : 0
});

console.log(people)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var people = [{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'other'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'dead'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'healthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'unhealthy'},{name: 'XXX',state: 'unhealthy'}];

console.log(_.sortBy(people,function(p, index){
 return p.name == 'healthy' ? -1 : ( p.name == 'unhealthy' ? -2 : index);
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple compare function should do the trick.

```
function test(a,b) {
  if (a.state === b.state) return 0;
  if (a.state === 'unhealthy') return .5;
  if (a.state === 'healthy') return 1;
  return -1
}

var sortedArray = people.sort(test);
```

Here is an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/lot224/xkmgrjL2/